# Finding minimal value in complex variable binding with Jess rules

Tags: java, rules, jess

I have designed the following Jess rule for finding minimal values of temperature observations which are structured based on a specific pattern in an ontology:

```
(defrule TemperatureMinObservation
(object 
    (is-a http://..#ObservationValue)
    (OBJECT ?ov)
    (http://..#hasDataValue ?a1)
) 
(not 
    (object 
        (http://..#hasDataValue ?a2&:(< ?a2 ?a1))))
(object (is-a http://..#SensorOutput) 
    (OBJECT ?so) 
    (http://..#hasValue ?ov))
(object (is-a http://..#Observation)
    (OBJECT ?o)
    (http://..#observationResult ?so)
    (http://..#qualityOfObservation ?qo&:(eq (instance-name ?qo) 
        (instance-name http://..#Temperature)))
)
=>
(printout t "Temperature minimal observation is " (instance-name ?o) " with value " ?a1 crlf))
```

The rule compiles and runs well but fails to provide the desired result: it does not give the minimal value from temperature observations but from all observations present in the ontology.

As adviced from the comments the restriction included in the not CE looks like follows:

```
(not 
    (object 
        (is-a http://..#ObservationValue)
        (OBJECT ?ov)
        (http://..#hasDataValue ?a2&:(< ?a2 ?a1))))
```

Runing the rule eith this modification resulted with printing the temperature observations and corresponding values like follows:

```
Temperature minimal observation is http://..#oo2805 with value 24.094999313354492
Temperature minimal observation is http://..#oo2809 with value 21.75
Temperature minimal observation is http://..#oo2904 with value 9.937999725341797 etc.
```

Comment: Not knowing what ObservationValue, Observation, SensorOutput and their attributes mean it's difficult to advise. - However, I find it strange that the object in the `not` CE does not restrict the type (`is-a`) and only references property `ObservationValue`.

Comment: `Observation` instances are linked with `SensorOutput` instances through `observationResult` object property. `SensorOutput` instances in turn are linked with `ObservationValue` instances through `hasValue` object property. Finally, `ObservationValues` are linked with integer values through datatype property `hasDataValue`

Comment: To find a minimum of `ObservationValue`s hasDataValue: I don't see a reason to include `SensorOutput` - an output value?!

Comment: The reason I bind the variables `?o` with `?so`, `?so` with `?ov` and, `?ov` with `?a1` is to filter observations to include only temperature ones (see `qualityOfObservation` slot value)

Comment: D'accord, but you have to do the same restrictioning thing for the not-ed object set.

Comment: @laune I modified the question to include your suggestion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75505/discussion-between-edi-and-laune).